# mashape unirest php test

Tags: php, composer-php, unirest, mashape

I have installed unirest though composer, but it does not return anything.
Is there anything wrong with this simple code?

```
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$response = Unirest\Request::get("https://contextualwebsearch-websearch-v1.p.mashape.com/api/Search/ImageSearchAPI?autoCorrect=true&count=50&q=Donald+Trump",
  array(
    "X-Mashape-Key" => "my key",
    "Accept" => "application/json"
  )
);

echo $response->body;
?>
```

(i have the key)

Comment: yep no `<?php` tag ... Unless you just forgot it in the question.

Comment: I didn't. But for some reason if you include it while using the <pre> code tag, it only showed half of the code. Hence, only the PHP code is shown.

Comment: It (stack overflow) probably only allows specific HTML tags, and it sees it as the start of a tag `<?php ... "X-Mashape-Key" =>`  I always indent my code on here.

Comment: I have asked at mashape if it's possible to use normal json query parsing instead of unirest. By the lack of response I assume you can't.